# Why @page is not working for printing an HTML page?

Tags: html, css, pdf, printing, media-queries

I used the `@media print` attribute to custom printing of pdf file.

Everything is going fine, but I didn't succeed to make the (page count / title) work  using `@page`.

**print.css**

```
@media print {
   @page {
        size: A4;

        @bottom-right {
            content: counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
        }
        @bottom-center {
            content: doctitle content();;
        }
    }
}
```

Do I need something more like a js library to make it work ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What HTML-to-PDF product/service are you using? If you're using anything like _"WKHtmlToPdf"_ and its clones (often based on Qt) I find they're using _almost decades-old_ builds of WebKit or Blink which predates support for the `@page` at-rule. So, what happens if you try it in a modern browser like Chrome 122?

Comment: I don't use any service, I only have `<link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" media='print' href='../styles/print.css'>` which refers to my css sheet.